# Incompatible peer dependency error when updating Angular version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Ionic/Angular project that I would like to update from Angular 12 to 13. This is my first time updating Angular core using the CLI.

I was following the details from Angular to perform the upgrade: https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=12.0-13.0 and have run into a few issues.

When running this command:

`ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13`

I receive this error:

```
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 13.3.7 to perform the update.
✔ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 61 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular-eslint/builder" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cli" (requires ">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0", would install "13.3.7").
✖ Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "/private/var/folders/sk/s5rpkp151bn8mjblpzqbdw5r0000gp/T/ng-22f6Fq/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Currently running node version `v14.17.0`. Is there anything else from my `package.json` I should be looking at updating first prior to updating Angular in my project for this upgrade to perform correctly?

Edit: This is my `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor-community/admob": "^3.2.0",
    "@capacitor-community/stripe": "^3.4.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^1.2.0",
    "@capacitor/clipboard": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.3.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "3.3.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/share": "^1.0.4",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.11.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.3.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
```

Comment: You've not shared your package.json... How would we know?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - sorry, I was trying to edit my post to include. It is in there now.

Comment: In order to ignore the peer dependencies and update, execute the following command: `ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force`

Comment: you need to updateyour @angular-eslint given that there are breaking changes between 12 and 13 version (it went from using TSlint to using ESLint) 

https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint

Comment: I appreciate the info @TomaszGolinski. I updated the original post to include my `devDependencies` as well, it looks like my project is already using ESLint.